# writing to excel in java

Tags: java, excel, excel-2007

Can someone point me in the right direction for writing to an excel file in java??
I am not understanding the links I found online. 
Could you just send me a link or anything which I could follow through??

Thank you,
J

Comment: What links are you talking about? There are lots of different ways to go about writing to excel files from Java. Is there a particular API or library you are having problems with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP generating Excel spreadsheet (XLS) to download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477886/jsp-generating-excel-spreadsheet-xls-to-download)

Comment: [GemBox.Spreadsheet for Java](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet-java/examples/java-excel-api-library/601) is really fast and the API is easy-to-use, [here is the writing example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet-java/examples/create-write-excel-file-in-java/402).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not to be banal, but Apache POI can do it. You can find some code examples here:
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html

Answer (score 13):

Another alternative to Apache POI is the [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), which (IMO) has an easier to use API. [Some examples](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html#writing):

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"));

WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);

Label label = new Label(0, 2, "A label record"); 
sheet.addCell(label); 

Number number = new Number(3, 4, 3.1459); 
sheet.addCell(number);
```

Comment: Awesome API. So much easier than Apache POI. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Posting useful examples for API's.

Step by step example for using [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/):

http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaExcel/article.html

http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jexcel/how-to-create-an-excel-file.html

Step by step example for using [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) (little old one but useful):

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2004/jw-0322-poi.html

Answer (score 2):

Here i'm going to give sample example,how to write excel;use this in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

**Model class:**

```
public class Products {    
    private String productCode1;    
    private String productCode2;    
    private String productCode3;   

    constructors,setters and getters    
}
```

**main class:**

```
public class WriteExcel {

    public void writeExcel() {

        Collection staff = new HashSet();    

        staff.add(new Products("101R15ss0100", "PALss Kids 1.5 A360 ", "321"));    
        staff.add(new Products("101R1ss50100", "PAL sKids 1.5 A360 ", "236"));    

        Map beans = new HashMap();    

        beans.put("products", staff);    
        XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();    

        try {    
            transformer.transformXLS(templateFileName, beans, destFileName);   

            System.out.println("Completed!!");    

        } catch (ParsePropertyException e) {    
            System.out.println("In ParsePropertyException");    
            e.printStackTrace();    
        } catch (IOException e) {    
            System.out.println("In IOException");    
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        WriteExcel writeexcel = new WriteExcel();    
        writeexcel.writeExcel();    
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ExcelUtils {

    private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
    private static XSSFCell Cell;
    private static XSSFRow Row;
    File fileName = new File("C:\\Users\\satekuma\\Pro\\Fund.xlsx");

    public void setExcelFile(File Path, String SheetName) throws Exception {
        try {
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
            ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
    }


    public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws      Exception {
        try {
            Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
            String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
            return CellData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static void setCellData(String Result, int RowNum, int ColNum, File Path) throws Exception {
        try {
            Row = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum - 1);
            Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum - 1);
            Cell.setCellValue(Result);
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Path);
            ExcelWBook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the basic code to write data in excel file (.xls).**

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

public class Export2Excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //create .xls and create a worksheet.
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\data2excel.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("My Worksheet");

            //Create ROW-1
            HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 0);

            //Create COL-A from ROW-1 and set data
            HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.createCell((short) 0);
            cellA1.setCellValue("Sno");
            HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GOLD.index);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellA1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            //Create COL-B from row-1 and set data
            HSSFCell cellB1 = row1.createCell((short) 1);
            cellB1.setCellValue("Name");
            cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.index);
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellB1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            //Create COL-C from row-1 and set data
            HSSFCell cellC1 = row1.createCell((short) 2);
            cellC1.setCellValue(true);

            //Create COL-D from row-1 and set data
            HSSFCell cellD1 = row1.createCell((short) 3);
            cellD1.setCellValue(new Date());
            cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat
                    .getBuiltinFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
            cellD1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            //Save the workbook in .xls file
            workbook.write(fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**NOTE:** *You need to download jar library from the link:* http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/poi/poi-3.9.jar.zip

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Apache's POI Library](http://poi.apache.org/) when I've had to write to excel files from Java. I found it rather straight forward once you get the hang of it. Java World has a good [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-05/01-qa-0503-excel3.html) about starting out using POI that I found very helpful.