# Writing data to excel sheet java

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to read data from database and then need to write the data to an excel/csv file in an java application. The data from database can be more than 10000 rows. So could someone suggest a nice solution taking into account the performance issue also.

Is there a way we can directly read and write to excel sheet.

Thanks in advance,
Kathy.

Comment: Try this tuto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454975/writing-to-excel-in-java

Comment: [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: Another solution for [writing Excel data in Java](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet-java/examples/create-write-excel-file-in-java/402), I find the API a bit cleaner and easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache POI to do this: http://poi.apache.org

Use the HSSFWorkbook as an abstraction of a .xls workbook. There's also a XSSF format for the newer XML-based Excel files (.xlsx, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI will best suits to your problem.

Try the following references example and document.

- http://poi.apache.org/
- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

The second reference will give you the whole implementation of how to work with POI.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to java excel you should try out [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Apache has a nice library that should meet your requirements.

Look into http://poi.apache.org/

Hope this helps.