# Writing comma separated numbers into one cell

Tags: java, excel, csv

I am generating CSV file using Java code with header fields say UserName, AccountNumbers.  Now for AccountNumber header field, I need to show all account numbers as comma separated in onc cell only.

ex. abc, **10001,10002,10003**

Now when I open the generated CSV file in excel, the account numbers are not displaying properly and that cell value is considered as Number, and by default Number format getting applied when opening in excel.

I applied below solutions :

1) wrapping the comma separated list in double quotes
        i.e. "10001,10002,10003" -- did not worked
2) wrapping the comma separated list in "=""list"""
        i.e. "=""10001,10002,10003""" -- problem with this wrapping is that, for some of the list it's working fine, but for some, I am getting "= appearing in start of the list.
i.e. some list are already considered as text format (not sure why)

```
HttpServletResponse response = this.getPortalPageContext().getResponse();
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=user_search_export.csv");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
Writer out = response.getWriter();
StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
tmp.append("UserName");
tmp.append("Accounts");
out.write(tmp.toString());
out.write("\r\n");

StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
String accountNo = "10001,10002,10003";
tmp.append("abc");
tmp.append("\"=\"\"" + accountNo + "\"\"\"");
out.write(tmp.toString());
out.write("\r\n");
```

Thanks

Comment: `Solution 1` should have worked perfectly! Can you edit the question and include the JAVA code that you have?

Comment: added java code.. thanks.

Comment: Try: `tmp.append("abc,"); tmp.append("\"" + accountNo + "\"");`

Comment: I had already tried this and output was --> abc 100,011,000,210,003

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use another delimiter as cell delimiter, like ';'. In the import wizard of excel you can choose this delimiter as cell delimiter only. When excel use the currency formatter for the last column, you can force text type for this column.

Comment: How we can specify/use another delimiter apart from comma for CSV ?

Comment: Here are my settings for the import https://ibb.co/mE3NyH and my result on the screen https://ibb.co/e1B9dH. You said in another comment, that your end users doesn't want to import - so csv is the wrong format for your usecase. You have to write native calc-files instead.

Comment: In a previous asked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454975/writing-to-excel-in-java was http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the text qualifier around your comma-separated string, and then **IMPORT**ing the file works as it should.

If the value is being split, be sure there is no <kbd>space</kbd> after that first comma (as there is in your example).

I will add some examples

**Content of csv file**

```
abc,"10001,10002,10003"
```

**Import using Legacy Wizard**

[image]

**step 2**

[image]

**step 3**

[image]

**on the worksheet**

[image]

Comment: End users doesn't want to import.. they just want to get it opened when they double clicked.

Comment: @Mrbond That is how Excel is designed. I suggest you generate an Excel file, rather than a CSV file, if the end users desires are paramount.  You could probably write a script which accomplishes the import, but they would have to click on that script, and then, from within the script, select the file.